# The User.IsInRole("Administrators") with IClaimsTransformer always false

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I add the role `administrators` to user claims after authentication with an `IClaimsTransformer` impelimentation like this:

`(principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrators"));`
But when i call  `User.IsInRole("Administrators")` in my Razor view it return false.

Comment: did you try adding the claim it exactly the same?, ie I would not assume it is case insensitive

Comment: Yes. I see the role in user claims when I debug it.

Comment: have you tried .HasClaim to see if it is any different? are you sure the check for the claim happens after the transformation?

Comment: `User.HasClaim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", "Administrators")` is true. But `User.IsInRole("Administrators")` is false.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar in an API-based solution, but I set the role claim when I create the user, instead of in a transformer.

After looking at the `User.IsInRole()` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx) it appears that this method is designed to pull from a cache first.

> IsInRole first checks the IsRoleListCached property to determine
>   whether a cached list of role names for the current user is available.
>   If the IsRoleListCached property is true, the cached list is checked
>   for the specified role. If the IsInRole method finds the specified
>   role in the cached list, it returns true. If IsInRole does not find
>   the specified role, it calls the GetRolesForUser method of the default
>   Provider instance to determine whether the user name is associated
>   with a role from the data source for the configured ApplicationName
>   value.

I suspect since `ClaimTypes.Role` is a common claim and not a custom domain-specific claim (which I believe is the use-case for a ClaimsTransformer), the application is using a default, cached, pre-transform value.

Much of this is speculation, though.  You may try setting the claim when you create the user.  I do it using the UserManager class.

```
var claimsResult = await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(applicationUser, new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, "Administrator"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem - when I added the claim to the already-existing identity `User.IsInRole` always returned false (even though I could see that the identity had that role), but when I added a second `ClaimsIdentity` with the claim it worked just fine:

```
var id = new ClaimsIdentity();

id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.RoleName));

// I actually returned a clone of the principal every time, not the original principal
clone.AddIdentity(id);
```

I admit that I don't completely understand why yet, but it worked for me.